# How to append classname to body tag if guest user

Tags: functions, customization

By default when a user is logged in, a 'logged-in' classname is appended to the body tag. I need to append something like 'guest-user' to the body to output different styling based on whether or not the user is logged in.

How can I achieve this? Something maybe I could put in my child theme's functions.php file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's the [body_class filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class). You could use e.g.

```
function body_class_guest_user( $classes, $class ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $classes[] = 'guest-user';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_guest_user', 10, 2 );
```

However you could equally well just use [the :not() selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), e.g. `body:not(.logged-in)` ([browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_not)), 
or absence of logged-in i.e. set up the guest-user styling as default but then override it if `.logged-in`.